# Debug JS Remotely

Tags: react-native, android-virtual-device, remote-debugging

I'm running react-native app on windows using AVD. App is ruuning without errors. But When I'm trying to debug the app remotely, it is throwing me an error saying:

> Unable to connect with remote debugger
>
> unexpected end of stream on connection

[image]
I set **Debug server host & port for device** to localhost:8081.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: did you start `http://localhost:8081/` in web browser ?

Comment: @HardikVirani this normaly happens automaticly when you start debug mode

Comment: but sometime it will open with wrong url as well

Comment: did you use this link in google chrome : http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/

Comment: I tried, but no use

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way of debugging code is to use Chrome. You don’t need to install any other apps.  on Android emulator, or shake real devices, you will see the in-app developer menu. Tap “Debug JS Remotely”. The Chrome debugger will be opened automatically. You still need to open Developer Tools in Chrome manually. Open source files in the Sources tab, you can set breakpoints here. (Update on Feb 26, 2018: due to a bug in React Native Android, 
if the app says it failed to connect the debugger and the URL in Chrome is not

http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/, change the URL to

http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/, kill the app, and try again.)

*All credit gose to this website : https://codeburst.io/react-native-debugging-tools-3a24e4e40e4*

[image]

[image]